# NullPointerException in sessionState$lzycompute Spark

Tags: mysql, scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to construct a custom receiver to get input stream from a MySQL database, but a `NullPointerException` appears.

```
class CustomReceiver(sqlContext: SQLContext, url: String) extends Receiver[DataFrame](StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2) {

    val connectionProperties = new Properties()
    connectionProperties.setProperty("user", "XXX")
    connectionProperties.setProperty("password", "XXX")
    connectionProperties.setProperty("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")


    def onStart() {
    // Start the thread that receives data over a connection
        new Thread("Database Receiver") {
          override def run() { receive() }
        }.start()
    }

    def onStop() {
    // There is nothing much to do as the thread calling receive()
    // is designed to stop by itself if isStopped() returns false
    }

    /** Create a database connection and receive data until receiver is stopped */
    private def receive() {

        var data:DataFrame = null

        try {

            val jdbcQuery = "SQL Query String"
            data = sqlContext.read.jdbc(url, jdbcQuery, connectionProperties)
            if (data != null) {
                store(data)
            }

            restart("Trying to connect again")
        } catch {
            case e: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException =>
                restart("MySQLSyntaxError", e)
            case n: java.lang.NullPointerException =>
                restart("NullPointer", n)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.<init>(DataFrameReader.scala:547)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.read(SparkSession.scala:595)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.read(SQLContext.scala:504)
        at CustomReceiver.CustomReceiver$$receive(receiver.scala:44)
        at CustomReceiver$$anon$1.run(receiver.scala:27
```

The error is from here:

```
data = sqlContext.read.jdbc(url, jdbcQuery, connectionProperties)
```

I think it is because the SQL Context can only be executed in the driver side. I can't find any answer to this question but I found some articles which said that it's impossible to stream from the database. Is this the reason the null pointer exception occurs?

Comment: i dont think its possible to stream from data base.

Comment: Is there any reason why we can't do that~?

Comment: technically, ter should be a sender/producer to stream the data. is any possibility of the DB u r using would stream it ? According to my knowledge , DBs cannot stream data out of the box.